# Bash Script to Replace one file in Listed systems

Tags: bash, script

I want to create a script to **replace** one file in listed CentOS systems under `/usr/bin`.

Eg: I need to **Copy & Replace** one file from a central location to multiple systems, (using root login).

path : `/storage1/data/client  /usr/bin/`

Can anyone help with this?

My list sample,

```
10.20.1.2
10.20.1.3
10.20.1.4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `scp` in a `for` loop?

```
for server in user1@server1 user2@server2 user3@server3
do
    scp /storage1/data/client "$server":/usr/bin/
done
```

If the servers are already in an array, you would use:

```
#!/bin/bash
for server in "${servers[@]}"
do
    scp /storage1/data/client "$server":/usr/bin/
done
```

If in a file (single server per line), you would write:

```
while IFS= read -r server
do
    scp /storage1/data/client "$server":/usr/bin/
done < serverfile
```

Of course you can manually add the `root` user if that is user you want to connect with (this also strips leading and trailing whitespace), like so:

```
while read server
do
    scp /storage1/data/client root@"$server":/usr/bin/
done < serverfile
```

If the number of servers is too large you could do the copying concurrently, like so:

```
for server in user1@server1 user2@server2 user3@server3
do
    scp /storage1/data/client "$server":/usr/bin/ &
done
wait
```

Comment: I've more than 100 systems, how Can I use a list in this.

Comment: @BloodHunter: What is a "list"? Do you mean an array, a file, something else?

Comment: a file with hostnames or ip's

Comment: @BloodHunter: See edit then on how to read the file line by line, if you can't make it work edit the question to add a sample of the file to show the precise format.

Comment: @BloodHunter: The fourth script should work with your file, and connect to all servers as root (assuming root login over `ssh` is enabled - that's not always the case).